# iOS error message: reason: '-[__NSArrayM length]:

Tags: ios, debugging, count, nsarray

So I'm getting this error message

```
reason: '-[__NSArrayM length]:
```

when this line is executed in my program

```
if (indexInTour == [tourArray count]-1)
```

Which I don't understand, since both values are defined at run-time.

This code runs fine when the view controller is pushed from one view controller, but crashes when pushed from a different one.

Also, I'm confused why

```
NSLog(@"%i", [tourArray count]);
```

works fine, while

```
if (indexInTour == [tourArray count]-1) // Crashes here
```

doesn't.

Some additional information:

Code:

```
NSLog(@"%i", [tourArray count]);
NSLog(@"%i", indexInTour);
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([tourArray class]));
// NSLog(@"%@", tourArray);

if (indexInTour == [tourArray count]-1) // Crashes here
```

Output:

```
2012-07-31 09:46:10.268 XXX[13374:11603] 7
2012-07-31 09:46:10.269 XXX[13374:11603] 2
2012-07-31 09:46:10.270 XXX[13374:11603] __NSArrayM
```

Full error message:

```
-[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a97f60
2012-07-31 09:50:26.696 XXX[13456:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a97f60'
```

Comment: Just before that line add this code: NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([tourArray class]) );

Comment: It seems the instance's class is: __NSArrayM

Comment: Try logging the array itself NSLog(@"%@", tourArray) ); I'm going to guess that some object in it has been dealloced or something, so the array is corrupted. My best guess anyway.

Comment: The array's content doesn't seem corrupted. Thanks for helping.

Comment: So this is a mutable array (other SO thread). This makes no sense - you dump the array's contents, it all looks good. but if you ask it its count, it crashes? Add one more NSLog(@"%d", [tourArray count]); It just has the look and feel of using a released item - tourArray is a strong property/ivar, right? Search SO for __NSArrayM - lots of threads.

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/5115344/96716 for ideas

Comment: tourArray is actually supposed to be an NSArray instance, not NSMutableArray. I'm not sure whether that should change anything. I've edited my post to add the log message.

Comment: And yes, tourArray is a property.

Comment: @HeryR. since it's a subclass, it shouldn't affect anything, btw the code you posted seems irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: What part of it is irrelevant? I don't get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like deallocation issue. Make sure that your property is declared as either `strong` or `retain`.

EDIT:

Based on the comments below, it appears that your `tourArray` contains `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSString`.

Comment: My property is declared as @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *tourArray; Can you think of anything I should or shouldn't do when using ARC, which could cause this error to happen?

Comment: Enable break on exception and check where is the `length` selector called from

Comment: It turns out length is called here:[directionTextLabel setText:[directionArray objectAtIndex:indexInTour]];

Comment: So the answer is: you are returning an NSArray from this code: :[directionArray objectAtIndex:indexInTour]. So the statement you started this thread had nothing to do with your problem. Next time PLEASE try to be more attentive to WHERE the problem is so we don't go wasting time.

Comment: Oh wow. I'm really sorry about that. But that taught me enabling breaking on exceptions and tracing method calls, so that wasn't so much of a waste of time.